# Dynamically add TextViews to Widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I decided to make a widget for my application but i got stucked in something!

I want to add  multiple textviews on the widget based on the size of an arrayList, but after searching Google i finally found out that this isn't possible.

Although i tried a lot of workarounds nothing seemed to work!

So i want to ask you for your help! Is it possible to do so even with predefined xml files and how to do so?

So what i am actually looking for is an appropriate piece of a code that demonstrates what i described above! Or any other help that can lead me to the solution of the problem!

Thanks in advance for your help!

/bump!
Anyone ?

Comment: You can just loop through the arrayList and create a new TextView every time you do so. Then just add it to the desired View. To create a TextView just use: TextView tv = new TextView(context); Then to add it to a View just call .addView(tv) on the desired View.

Comment: Well i tried this and it doesnt work! That's why i stated in my question that only predefined xml TextViews are allowed but i dont know how to achieve something like that!

Comment: If you would like to use XML code, use an Inflater

Comment: Can you provide a valid sample of code to achieve this?

Comment: Say you have an XML file with the TextView you would like to use. 
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); Then you can call inflate on the inflater object to get that as a View, then just add it to your outer view as normal. You can have a look here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Comment: Can you fill the above comment with more details and make it an answer ? I will check if it will work and i will accept it if it does!

Comment: Hey dude! I had no luck either. Can you provide more details on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. You have to do it like this:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget); // your widget layout xml
for (...){
    RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.empty_item); // xml with just a textview
    view.setTextViewText(R.id.textviewId, "some dynamic text"); // id of the textview and some text
    views.addView(R.id.layout, view); // id of the layout in widget.xml    
}
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible.

However, you could use one multi-line TextView.

Answer (score -1):

```
  TextView[] tx = new TextView[10];
    TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[10];
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        tx[i] = new TextView(this);
        tx[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tx[i].setText("Data")
        tr[i] = new TableRow(this);
        tr[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr[i].addView(tx[i]);
        // and then adding table row in tablelayout
    }
```

Comment: As i said at the comments above this is not working for widgets!

Comment: do you have limit on the ARray size? < 10, < 25? If yes, we can think of alternate solution :)... I believe, it shouldn't be more...

Comment: Theoretically yes it has a limit but it is userdefined so it can vary a lot concerning the upper bound!

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work if you stick this in your onCreate:

```
View myView  = (View)findViewById(R.id.Something);

for(element : array) {

    TextView myTV = new TextView(context);
    myTV.setText(array.getText());
    myView.addView(myTV);

}
```

Comment: Nope this doesnt work for Widgets! I am working with an AppWidgetProvider extended class not an Activity!

Comment: The instead of findViewByID .. you use RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.mywidget);

Comment: I know that but adding TextViews on runtime like this just doesnt work! It has to be an xml predefined and i stated that on my question!

Comment: So why can you not use the above and update your widget with an AppWidgetManager

Comment: Because as i said you this doesnt work for widgets! I already tried it and also tried similar workarounds without any luck!

Comment: Have you tried extending the AppWidgetProvider and in the onUpdate method, get the RemoteViews, add/modify/delete them and then use an AppWidgetManager to update them? I have never had any problems doing that.

Comment: Yeah i did the same thing then added the layout to the remoteviews and the updated the widget and it didnt work!